# Removing from collection based on values from another collection - Lambda/Linq

Tags: c#, lambda, observablecollection

Okay this is the problem:

I have 2 list's with cars

```
ObservableCollection<Car> carlist1;
ObservableCollection<Car> carlist2;
```

And the car object has a car brand and an engine size, but i wound like to end up with carlist1 only having the cars that carlist2 doesn't have based on the brand.

carlist1 contains:

```
car (mazda, 1.6)
car (audi 2.4)
car (golf 2.0)
```

and carlist2 contains:

```
car (mazda 1.6)
car (mazda 1.0)
car (audi 2.0)
car (mercedes 2.8)
```

so i would like carlist1 to just have the golf in this example.

This is my code to do so:

```
        foreach (car c2 in carlist2)
        {
            foreach (car c1 in carlist1)
            {
                if (c1.Brand == c2.Brand)
                {
                    carlist1.remove(c1)
                    break;
                }
            }
         }
```

How do i convert this to LINQ or Lambda?

Comment: It's not clear what `carlist2` has to do with it, to be honest. You could make `carlist1` just have unique brands without `carlist2` being involved at all...

Comment: On top of that, `carlist1` already contains unique brands. Can't your control what's being added to list to keep it unique?

Comment: sorry.. seems like my mind was somewhere else.. updated the question..

Comment: Since it's an ObservableCollection, I assume you want to remove from the existing collection and not create a new one, so that you don't lose the observers?

Comment: well it doesn't matter that much, i just need the carlist1 without objects from carlist 2..

Comment: `carlist1 = carlist1.Except(carlist2)`?

Comment: @PeterRitchie but i want to sort by the name..

Comment: @mathias Sort by name? Where did you mention that?

Comment: sorry not sort by the name like that, but i want to identify them, by name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removal has to be done with `foreach` (as LINQ isn't supposed to alter collections), but other than that you can fetch unwanted brands and then items to remove from `carlist1` with LINQ:

```
var carlist2Brands = carlist2
    .GroupBy(c => c.Brand)
    .Select(g => g.Key)
    .ToArray();
var carsToRemove = carlist1
    .Where(c => carlist2Brands.Contains(c.Brand))
    .ToArray();
foreach (var car in carsToRemove)
{
    carlist1.Remove(car);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful to write a 'RemoveWhere' extension, which will enable you to write:

```
var brandsToRemove = list2.Select(c => c.Brand);
list1.RemoveWhere(c => brandsToRemove.Contains(c.Brand));
```

The extension looks like:

```
    public static void RemoveWhere<T>(this List<T> list, Predicate<T> predicate)
    {
        foreach (var ele in list)
        {
            if (predicate(ele))
                list.Remove(ele);
        }
    }
```